# img import bug on the React/Next js site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, import, next.js

community. Recently I faced one very annoying bug in my React/Next JS site.

I can’t display any image if I’m using src='/static/images/service'/>. Importing and assigning a route like this: `import Image1 from "../../static/images/service.png";` to js variable doesn’t help either.

According to the Next Js documentation all assets should strictly be stored in “/static” folder which is in the root folder by itself.

Strangely that I can access images with no problem using background-image in CSS

`background-image: url("../../static/images/service.png");` but not in the `<img/>` way. Which is the only option for me because I'm using .map method to render images and give them the path from an array.

Plus I have all possible loaders for different types of files installed.

What might be the issue for this behavior?

Link to my repo: https://github.com/kkdima/barva

To test it on your machine:

```
git clone https://github.com/kkdima/barva.git

npm i

npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of giving path in src of img tag. import it in your file and then use it. it will hopefully fix the problem. code below:

```
import Image1 from "../../static/images/service.png";
```

and then provide the src like this:

```
<img src={Image1} />
```

Comment: I mentioned it above, this approach also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to add Image loader in **next.config.js**. You can use **next-images** package for that. Below is the link of package :

https://github.com/twopluszero/next-images